# Cosa significa "bracconeria"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *La Luna come un fungo*, una "cosmicomica" di Italo Calvino, ho letto:

> Per Bm Bn il trovarsi lì era solo un'occasione per nuove piraterie, *bracconerie*,
>   devastazioni.

Ho cercato il vocabolo "bracconeria" in alcuni dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il suo significato?

Comment: Refuso per *bricconerie*?

Comment: @egreg: Si tratta di un'edizione di Mondadori: non so se i libri di Mondadori a volte contengono refusi. Per di più, è un racconto che è stato pubblicato molte volte, alcune di queste edizioni si trovano su Google Books e sembra che in tutte appaia "bracconerie".

Comment: Ogni libro contiene refusi. Qui potrebbe essere un'assonanza voluta o involontaria: il bracconaggio non ha molto a che fare con pirateria e devastazione.

Comment: Non so che edizione abbia Charo: per quel che vale, ho controllato sui Meridiani e anche lì dice “bracconerie”.

Comment: @DaG: Ecco l'edizione che ho con me: Italo Calvino, *Tutte le cosmicomiche* (Oscar Mondadori, Oscar grandi classici, 2011).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Penso sia una variante dialettale/regionale di

[Bracconaggio:](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/B/bracconaggio.php) :

> - Caccia illegale, fatta in tempi o luoghi non consentiti, o senza regolare licenza; caccia di frodo.

Treccani online ci dice che l'origine viene dal francese *bracconage,* da cui deriva anche il verbo (raro) ***[bracconare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bracconare/) ossia cacciare con il bracco.***

[Bracconaggio](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bracconaggio/) s. m. ***(dal fr. braconnage, der. di braconner: v. bracconare)***

Come ci dice [Wikipedia](https://it.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracconaggio) il bracconaggio è una pratica molto antica e, a mio avviso, il termine può avere assunto declinazioni dialettali nel corso dei secoli.

- Bracconeria assomiglia molto al verbo bracconare.

> - Con la nascita della proprietà privata tribale e con il sopraggiungere del medioevo, la selvaggina divenne un esclusivo patrimonio dei feudatari, dei regnanti e dei loro ospiti. Ciò privò il popolo di una delle fonti alimentari, dando vita al bracconaggio.

Comment: È plausibile, ma in questo caso si tratterebbe della pesca illegale. I personaggi del racconto sono esseri che vivono della pesca in un mondo tutto ricoperto di acqua e tra loro vale la regola che ognuno peschi soltanto nella zona che gli è assegnata. Questo personaggio, Bm Bn, viene definito nel racconto come un pirata.

Comment: Sapresti dirmi in quali regioni si usa?

Comment: Vedo che la definizione di [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracconaggio) parla anche di "pesca di frodo".

Comment: @Charo - io non sono di Roma, ma ho il sospetto che nel centro Italia  il termine  'bracconare' sia usato a livello dialettale. Forse qualche user ce lo può confermare.

Answer (score 2):

braccare: (dal vocabolario Sabatini Coletti)

1. Nella caccia, inseguire, stanare la selvaggina
2. (fig.) Dare la caccia a qualcosa o qualcuno senza tregua.

Bracconeria (o bracconaggio) di solito si usa soprattutto relativo alla caccia di frodo, cioè cacciare animali protetti o comunque in zone dove è vietato. Per estensione, si può usare nel senso di "ruberia" o di eseguire azioni illecite come la frode o simili.

Comment: La caccia di frodo è chiamata _bracconaggio_.

Comment: Potresti citare la fonte del dizionario?

Comment: Bracconeria e bracconaggio sono la stessa cosa, o comunque hanno lo stesso significato.

Comment: Andrea, puoi citare un dizionario che riporti “bracconeria”? Fino a prova contraria, mi sembra un'invenzione di Calvino.

Comment: Non ho trovato nessun vocabolario che riporti "bracconeria" ma dalle mie parti si usa con lo stesso significato di bracconaggio, quindi per me non è stato un problema spiegarne il significato.

Comment: Tra l'altro, “bracconaggio” non deriva da “braccare”. Entrambi vengono alla lunga dal “bracco”, ma per vie diverse.

Comment: @DaG: Comunque, una ricerca su Google Books conferma che questo vocabolo appare in alcuni altri libri (non molti però) e sembra avere questo significato.

Answer (score 1):

Il termine *bracconeria/e* non è corretto. È da richiamare il fatto che i soggetti che praticano *bracconaggio* sono i *bracconieri*, termine di uso molto più comune rispetto ai sopracitati, almeno nel colloquiale.

> Penso ci siano stati dei bracconieri => comune
>   Penso ci sia stato del bracconaggio  => raro

Quindi, per sviluppo dialettale, direi che la *bracconeria* è derivante dal termine *bracconiere* come oggetto del verbo "bracconare":

> Penso ci siano state delle *bracconerie*